# Obfuscated assembly detected by antivirus ( false positive)

Tags: obfuscation, antivirus, false-positive, virus-scanning, rpx

I have obfuscated a dotnet winform application with [Confuser](http://confuser.codeplex.com/) and then packed with [RPX Packer](http://rpx.codeplex.com/), now the resulting assembly is being given false positive by antiviruses like Kaspersky( deleting it), Avast etc.( Windows defender is OK with it). I am unable to figure out why?

How do i fix the issue

Comment: It could be as simple as changing the filename - you may have happened to have used one which is also used by some malware. Otherwise, contact the anti-virus software vendors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the RPX Packer which causes some Anti Virus scanners to identify the file as infected. I have had the same problem with a RPX packed executeable today. Think about dropping RPX.